# Subtract one column from another in data frame

Tags: r, dataframe

I've got a data frame, `df`, with the following columns:

```
> names(df)
[1] "survived"        "sex"             "age"            
[4] "pclass"          "sibsp"           "predict.t_tree."
```

How do I do an element-wise subtraction of `predict.t_tree` from `survived`? It would be nice if I could just have the result as an array or something and not update the data frame itself.

Here's some example data:

```
> typeof(df$survived)
[1] "integer"

> head(df$survived,5)
[1] 1 1 0 0 0

> typeof(df$predict.t_tree)
[1] "integer"

> head(df$predict.t_tree,5)
[1] 1 0 1 0 1
Levels: 0 1
```

The following code just gives an error:

```
> df$survived - df$predict.t_tree


Warning message:
In Ops.factor(df$survived, df$predict.t_tree) : - not meaningful for factors
```

Comment: add some example data of your data.frame.

Comment: The error message is pretty clear. One or both of your columns is not integer or numeric type and is a factor.

Comment: thanks, it thinks one is on "levels" but all values are integers. Anyway to change it? Using typeof(), both columns appear to be integers though...

Comment: You can either read your file with `StringsAsFactors=FALSE` or do `df$col <- as.numeric(as.character(df$col))`

Comment: @JoeDanger If you found one of the answers useful, i suggest you accept it as this is how the site works.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let's look at the output:

```
> typeof(df$survived)
[1] "integer"

> head(df$survived,5)
[1] 1 1 0 0 0

> typeof(df$predict.t_tree)
[1] "integer"

> head(df$predict.t_tree,5)
[1] 1 0 1 0 1
Levels: 0 1    <~~~~~ **** NOTICE HERE ****
```

When you see `"Levels: ____ "` That tells you that the vector (or column) is a 'factor' and not a string or a number.  If you are expecting anything other than a `factor`, then you must convert it, generally with an `as.character(.)` first. (Be *very* very cautious of using `as.numeric(.)` directly on a factor, as it is likely not the results you will be seeking)

---

Once converted, the pairwise manipulation is a cinch:

```
df$predict.t_tree <- as.numeric(as.character(df$predict.t_tree))

# Then, this will give you what you are after
df$survived - df$predict.t_tree
```

Answer (score 2):

Try the following with your data:

```
as.numeric(as.character(df$survived)) - df$predict.t_tree
```

**EDIT**
Added a small example

```
df <- data.frame(x = c("1", "2", "3"),
                 y = 1:3)

str(df)
# 'data.frame': 3 obs. of  2 variables:
#  $ x: Factor w/ 3 levels "1","2","3": 1 2 3
# $ y: int  1 2 3
```

The x column is of type factor. You have to coerce the data type to numeric to be able to perform mathematical operations.

```
as.numeric(df$x) - df$y
```

[This is answered also in the FAQ: 7:10](http://www.hep.by/gnu/r-patched/r-faq/R-FAQ_61.html)

Comment: The problem was that your numeric data in `survived` was actually coded as a factor and not a number.

Answer (score 0):

`df$predict.t_tree` was created as a factor

```
df$predict.t_tree = as.numeric(as.character(df$predict.t_tree))
df$survived - df$predict.t_tree
```

Comment: It works! Thanks! Why does it need the as.character function?

Comment: In your case it is probably not necessary as the level 0 will map to the value 0 and the same for 1. But you will need it if your levels start > 0.